# Would Vue.js work with diffsync?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a number of client Vue.js applications I'd like to keep in sync with an in-memory JSON object on a node.js instance using http://janmonschke.com/projects/diffsync.html

Changes to the JSON object should be propagated to the clients but not the other way around. Sorts of like a one-way firebase.

Has anyone tried something like this? Would this work?

Comment: How is this too broad when I am specifying exactly what I want to do and with what??

Comment: It would probably work with Vuex and `replaceState`.

Comment: Because it's a yes/no question. Yes it could work.